# Ошибка в формуле в ворде для таблицы

Tags: ms-word

в чем ошибка данной формуле

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2+A1+B1+С1>A2+B2+B1+C1;A2+A1+B1+С1;ЕСЛИ(A2+B2+B1+C1>A2+B2+C2+C1;A2+B2+B1+C1;A2+B2+C2+C1))
```

результат пишет: Синтексическая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем уверен, что задачка относиться к ms-word, скорее к ms-excel.
Во-первых, скопировав вашу формулу `=ЕСЛИ(A2+A1+B1+С1>A2+B2+B1+C1;A2+A1+B1+С1` я получил информацию, что в формуле вы используете русскую букву С в паре моментов, конкретно в самом начале если(A2+A1+B1+**с1**>A2+B2+B1+C1;A2+A1+B1+**с1**
Поправьте на латинские заглавные и формула будет работать.

[Можете сами проверить на стороннем сервисе](http://www.cyr-lat.progresssite.pro/)

Comment: я очень извиняюсь, а как все таки работают точки с запятой внутри условия? просто никкогда не имел дела с excel

Comment: @S.H. формула начинается со знака `=` там операции с ячейками. Можно добавить функции, сначала идет имя, например `ЕСЛИ`, затем круглые скобки, обозначающие, что там должны быть данные относящиеся к формуле. Если параметров больше одного, то они разделяются `;`, если внутри функции нужно добавить еще функцию, то на нужном месте также пишете имя функции, круглые скобки и так далее. В EXCEL, как и других электронных таблицах можно заполнять данные через форму, тогда о `;` можно не беспокоиться.